# How to import and use C3D data in 2.8x?

Tags: add-on, import, motion-capture

I would like to apply a mocap animation onto my armature but I don't know what to import C3D files properly. Almost all of the search results yield a link to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499320/how-to-import-c3d-files-into-blender) and my Problem is that I can not find any "C3D Graphics Labs Motion Capture files addon" for 2.81a.

There are 2 or 3 other C3D import addons for Blender I found but they're all 3-6 years old, not maintained anymore and thus won't work with 2.8x. Another addon that is mentioned is "Motion Capture Tools" but I can not find this addon in 2.81a either.

**Q:** Is there any way to use my C3D data in 2.8x?